# (Highchart) 24 Hours chart: Link last point with first

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts

I have to program a machine with multiple values throughout the day, and besides, I need to graph a line with these values for intermediate values. To this should link the last point on the graph with the first.

At the moment I created an extra point at the start and end to repeat the last and the first value respectively but in the next day and the previous.

[image: first chart example]

But the problem comes when I change these values and I want to render the graphic (it is an AngularJS application with draggable points plugin in future versions), for example when set the first point to 23:00. I should modify several points, including the extra, but it's very hard, because some of these points are calculated (circles), in fact, only have 3 points in this chart (squares)...

[image: error chart example]

Is there any way to avoid these additional points (at the begining and the end) and use only those with real or calculated values? Have Highcharts some property to create a 24h "cyclic linear chart" or something similar?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve but maybe you can use step parameter? http://jsfiddle.net/yuuqeeLt/ I think that your current issue is from the fact that you don't have sorted data. Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need to reorder points ... I need to give values to the points and have them always connected, the last with the first. That is, if today I have 15 at 5:00 and 20 at 22:00, tomorrow I will be 15 at 5:00 and 20 at 22:00, and I need a line that represents the intermediate values in a graph 24 hours.

I hope I have explained myself better.

Comment: Its like set connectends parameter to true, but in 24h linear chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ky0yue7/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.connectEnds